# Executable file in venv\Scripts not recognised as a command

Tags: python, windows, console-application, virtualenv

I have cloned a github repository - [pypastry](https://github.com/datapastry/pypastry) - onto my Windows machine, and run `pip install -e pypastry` to install it in my virtual environment, so the project structure is like this:

```
│-- pypastry
|-- venv
    |-- Scripts
        |-- pastry
```

The executable file, called 'pastry', is sitting in venv\Scripts as I would expect, but Command Prompt isn't recognising it, and I am receiving the error:

```
'pastry' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I don't think it's a problem with PATH as the first item in PATH is `C:\Users\User\Documents\pypastry\venv\Scripts`.

This is the executable file itself:

```
#!c:\users\user\documents\pypastry\venv\scripts\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: 'pypastry==0.0.1','pastry'
__requires__ = 'pypastry==0.0.1'
__import__('pkg_resources').require('pypastry==0.0.1')
__file__ = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\pypastry\\pypastry\\pastry'
with open(__file__) as f:
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

Can anyone spot anything in this file which might mean it's not recognised as an executable on Windows or think of anything else that could be going wrong?

EDIT TO ADD:

If I run the file with the explicit python invocation (`python pypastry\pastry`) it works, but I don't want to have to do this as it creates other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is telling you that it does not find an executable called "pastry" (`pastry.exe`, `pastry.com`, `pastry.bat`, `pastry.cmd` ...) on your PATH.

But `pastry.py` is. Isn't it? The problem is that your windows is not configured to recognize `.py` as an executable extension.

To run python scripts in Windows without the explicit invocation of `python.exe`, you need first to have the `.py` extension associated to the executable python. And then the `.py` extension added as an executable extension.

You do so in three steps:

1. Associate the .py extension to a PythonFile file type

   ```
    ASSOC .py=PythonFile
   ```
2. Associate the PythonFile to your python.exe executable

   ```
    FTYPE PythonFile="c:\users\user\documents\pypastry\venv\scripts\python.exe" "%1" %*
   ```
3. Associate the .py file extension as one of the default executable extensions

   ```
    SET PATHEXT=.py;%PATHEXT%
   ```

Comment: This is a helpful explanation and I have followed steps 1, 2 and 3 in order. .py is now in my PATHEXT (twice actually): 
 .py;.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW

The problem is I am still getting the same error message - I wonder if the issue is that the file is just called 'pastry', with no .py extension?

Comment: avoiding extension is the purpouse of pathext, can't debug your installation from here, are you sure that your pathext is the actual used?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would check whether pathext is that actual used.. the executable file itself has a shebang at the top of it: #!/usr/bin/env python ... I'm not sure if that may be affecting my command prompt's ability to recognise it as an executable as that seems like a unix-specific line.. but still having the same problems with this